# Django admin: can I define fields order?

Tags: django

I use abstract models in Django like:

```
class Tree(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', default=None, null=True, blank=True,
                               related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_parent")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Genre(Tree):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

And all fields from the abstract model go first in Django's admin panel:

```
parent:
abstract_field2:
title:
model_field2:
...
```

Is there a way to put them (fields from abstract classes) in the end of the list?
Or a more general way to define order of fields?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can order the fields as you wish using the [`ModelAdmin.fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-options) option.

```
class GenreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('title', 'parent')
```

Comment: Also want to mention https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt if you need a tree structure

Comment: The order of fields would depend on the order in which you declare them in your models. So  alternatively you could order the fields in the way you would want them to show in the admin.

Comment: @larry in the question, `parent` is from the parent model `Tree`, and `title` is from the child model `Genre`, so it's not possible to change the order in the admin by changing the order in the models.

Comment: Guess this only applies in normal model situations.

Comment: For some reason (don't know why) including my timestamp fields (`created_at and updated_at`) causes crash when trying to edit (Error 500) if they aren't also included to `read_only`-fields. Perhaps because of `auto_add_now=True`?

Answer (score 10):

Building off rbennell's answer I used a slightly different approach using the new [get_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method introduced in Django 1.7. Here I've overridden it (the code would be in the definition of the parent's ModelAdmin) and removed and re-appended the "parent" field to the end of the list, so it will appear on the bottom of the screen. Using .insert(0,'parent') would put it at the front of the list (which should be obvious if you're familiar with python lists).

```
def get_fields (self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    fields = super().get_fields(request, obj, **kwargs)
    fields.remove('parent')
    fields.append('parent') #can also use insert
    return fields
```

This assumes that your fields are a list, to be honest I'm not sure if that's an okay assumption, but it's worked fine for me so far.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) for `get_fields` say "... is expected to return a list of fields ...", so I guess your assumption is okay.

Answer (score 6):

I know it's an old question, but wanted to thow in my two cents, since my use case was exactly like this, but i had lots of models inheriting from one class, so didn't want to write out fields for every admin. Instead I extended the get_form model and rearranged the fields to ensure parent always comes at the end of the fields in the admin panel for add/change view.

```
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(BaseAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        parent = form.base_fields.pop('parent')
        form.base_fields['parent '] = parent 
        return form
```

base_fields is an OrderedDict, so this appends the 'parent' key to the end.
Then, extend this admin for any classes where you want parent to appear at the end:

```
class GenreAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    pass
```

Comment: oh, i should add this is python 2.7. In python 3 it's even easier, using form.base_fields.move_to_end('parent')

Comment: Very smart way! Great

Answer (score 1):

This simple solution from @acquayefrank (in the comments) worked for me:

> The order of fields would depend on the order in which you declare them in your models.